# Can you use a BlobTrigger for a blob container with millions of blobs?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-blob-trigger

I have an existing blob container with over 3 million blobs in it.  I have written an Azure Function using BlobTrigger and a Blob output binding to copy the file, including it's tags, to another container on another storage account.

The [Azure docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger) seem to indicate BlobTrigger for a standard Blob Storage container is not recommended or perhaps not supported or possible for "high-scale" containers (containers with over 100,000 blobs in them).

My function is working against this container, but it does take about 9 minutes between startup, when the host lock lease is acquired, until the first files start processing.

The problem is, I need to process the existing files, and none of the other options in that Azure doc seem to support processing of existing blobs.

Do I proceed with the function I have, or should I avoid using it due to it's long start time?  Perhaps one of the event based ones are better, but then how do I "catch up" on the existing files first?

Comment: For existing files I would use azcopy, it can preserve tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do agree with @Peter Bons that for existing files you can use `azcopy` command with which we can copy files and tags can be preserved too and followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs-copy#copy-a-directory) :

```
azcopy copy 'https://mysourceaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myBlobDirectory' 'https://mydestinationaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer' --recursive
```

If you want to copy containers, directories, and blobs:

```
azcopy copy 'https://mysourceaccount.blob.core.windows.net/' 'https://mydestinationaccount.blob.core.windows.net' --recursive
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at doing a one-time AzCopy to catch up, and invest some time looking at doing an Event Grid subscription for the ongoing replication.

Comment: This doesn't seem to retain the tags from the source blobs and the copied ones.  Is there a switch that does it?  --blob-tags doesn't seem to be the one either.  That is if you want to set the tag on the copied blobs, if I'm reading the docs right.  EDIT: found the right command line option.  It's called --s2s-preserve-blob-tags